# How to add second y-axis to the bar chart? Altair

Tags: python, python-3.x, altair

I have a DataFrame:

```
  EMOJI   PERCENT_TEXT    PERCENT     combined
0           23.1%        23.1        23.1%
1           5.7%          5.7        5.7% 
2           3.5%          3.5        3.5%
3           3.0%          3.0        3.0%
4           2.5%          2.5        2.5%
5            2.4%          2.4          2.4%
```

My code is below:

```
bars = alt.Chart(percentages_df).mark_bar(color='orange').encode(
    alt.X('PERCENT:Q',axis=None),
    alt.Y('combined:N', sort='-x', title=None)
).configure_view(strokeOpacity=0).configure_axis(
    # remove axis line
    grid=False, domain=False,ticks=False
)
```

[image]

But the chart I created is not what I expected.

I want to create a bar chart by Altair with two y-axis labels, like this:
[image]

Should I use layer to generate this chart? If so, how to generate layers of two y-axis labels? If not, what should I use to generate it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to align the emojis to the left and the numbers to the right in the tick labels?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if there's a way to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any easy way to create two distinct sets of axis labels, but you can roughly accomplish the alignment you want by adjusting axis label properties.

I also changed the chart to create the combined label using a transform:

```python
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

percentages_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'EMOJI': ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
  'PERCENT': [23.1, 5.7, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.4]
})

alt.Chart(percentages_df).transform_calculate(
    combined = alt.datum.EMOJI + '    ' + alt.datum.PERCENT + '%'
).mark_bar(color='orange').encode(
    alt.X('PERCENT:Q',axis=None),
    alt.Y('combined:N', sort='-x', title=None,
          axis=alt.Axis(labelAlign='left', labelPadding=6))
).configure_view(strokeOpacity=0).configure_axis(
    # remove axis line
    grid=False, domain=False,ticks=False
)
```

[image: chart]

Another option is to concatenate two charts, one of which has no x-encoding:

```python
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

percentages_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'EMOJI': ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
  'PERCENT': [23.1, 5.7, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.4]
})

right = alt.Chart(percentages_df).mark_bar(color='orange').encode(
    alt.X('PERCENT:Q',axis=None),
    alt.Y('PERCENT:N', sort='-x', title=None)
)

left = alt.Chart(percentages_df).mark_text().encode(
    alt.Y('EMOJI:N', sort=alt.EncodingSortField('PERCENT', order="descending"), title=None)
)

alt.hconcat(
    left, right
).configure_view(strokeOpacity=0).configure_axis(
    # remove axis line
    grid=False, domain=False,ticks=False
)
```

[image: chart 2]

Comment: it shows SyntaxError: invalid syntax for labelPadding=6[![enter image description here][1]][1]0))

Comment: Sorry, stray image insertion. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try padding the string you use for labelling with whitespace via `rjust`. For this to work, you have to use a monospace font so that all characters are of equal with:

```
# With your df above
df['LABEL'] = df['EMOJI'] + df['PERCENT_TEXT'].str.rjust(8)

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(color='orange').encode(
    alt.X('PERCENT:Q',axis=None),
    alt.Y('LABEL:N', sort='-x', title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelFont='Droid Sans Mono'))
).configure_view(strokeOpacity=0).configure_axis(
    grid=False, domain=False,ticks=False
)
```

[image]